# My Bat File for my python program is not running although I put in correct commands and paths

Tags: python, batch-file

I wrote a simple python program and I'm trying to run it on a batch file, and I've checked all the possible errors I could have made on the batch file and it doesn't seem like I've done anything wrong, but when I run the batch file it opens the command prompt and does nothing else, like nothing ever happened.

My batch file looks like this

```
@echo off
"C:\Users\Vikraant\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe"
"C:\Users\Vikraant\Documents\Python Practice Files\BPA_Practice"
pause
```

And there are no errors on my python code when I run it, it runs fine when I put it through the IDE.

Comment: Python and the file name go on the same line

Comment: One line only example ```@"%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe" "%UserProfile%\Documents\Python Practice Files\BPA_Practice.py" & Pause```. If you haven't defined the working directory within your `.py` script, and it is required, then other alternatives are ```@CD /D "%UserProfile%\Documents\Python Practice Files" 2>NUL && "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe" "BPA_Practice.py" & Pause```, or ```@Start /D "%UserProfile%\Documents\Python Practice Files" "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe" "BPA_Practice.py" & Pause```.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check whether python is installed in your machine by running python --version command.

If Python is available. Place the below command in the bat file.

```
python C:\Users\Vikraant\Documents\Python Practice Files\BPA_Practice.py
```

I am assuming BPA_Practive.py is the python file you are trying to run.
Try to run it in a command window, so that you know what is happening.

Comment: I tried this, still nothing happened (the Python file worked when I ran it through command prompt).

Comment: That is because the code above is missing important doublequotes.

Comment: The posted command line does not work. The help of the *Windows Command Processor* output on running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window explains the reason. A file name (or any other argument string) containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` (or literally to interpret `<>|`) must be enclosed in `"`. The space character is otherwise interpreted as argument string separator. Correct would be `python.exe "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Python Practice Files\BPA_Practice.py"` whereby Compo posted an even better command line for usage in a batch file.